# I'm using AJAX to post an object from javascript to php within the same page and I'm getting the entire html page instead of the object

Tags: javascript, php

**instead of getting the object as the responce data I'm getting the entire html page (the page I'm posting to)  therefore I cannot retrieve the object in the php script**

```
                     //this is an example of the object not the actual abject
                     var data={lat:"1.098", lng:"31", city:"durban"};

                     $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "/webapp/index.php/",
                              data: data,
                              async:true,
                          
                              cache: false,
                              success: function(data)
                              {
                                alert(data.status);
                                console.log(data);
                              },
                                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                                alert(status);
                                alert(xhr.responseText);
                              }
                          });
```

Comment: Please add your index.php script to the question

Answer (score 0):

Since the server will **consume** `<?php /*some PHP scripts */` but than return the following `<!DOCTYPE html><html> etc...` as response - [you need to `exit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

<sub>index.php</sub>

```html
<?php
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   // Handle POST requests here 
   echo "HELLO WORLD!";
   exit;  // <<< You need to exit here!
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><!-- head stuff --></head>
<body>
    
  SOME FORM

  <script>
     // Some AJAX to "self" (index.php)
     // success response: "HELLO WORLD!"
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or even shorter:

```php
exit("HELLO WORLD!");
```